# Как скрыть метод родителя от дочерних классов php?

Tags: php, ооп, extend

Как объявить конструктор в родительском классе так, чтобы в дочерних классах он отсутствовал. Я порылся в доках, и как-то не получилось ответить на свой вопрос. Например:

```
class A{
  private function __construct(){ 
    echo 'Only class A';
  }
}
class B extends A{
//падает с ошибкой Call to private A::__construct() from invalid contex
}
$b = new B();
print_r(get_class_methods($b)); // нужен пустой array()
```

Comment: Если вы ставите вопрос таким образом и не принимаете ответ камрада @cheops, то единственный способ добиться возврата пустого массива при вызове функции get_class_methods() на экземпляре дочернего класса и скрытия метода (любого) родителя от наследников, это не объявлять метод (в частности конструктор) вообще. Иначе вы не понимаете наследование в php.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Конструктор следует объявить закрытым (private)

```
<?php
class A{
  private function __construct(){
    echo 'Only class A';
  }
}
class B extends A{
  function __construct(){}
}
$b = new B();
print_r(get_class_methods($b)); // пустой array()
```

Comment: Это же так логично. Я не удосужился проверить сам, видимо из-за поздней ночи. Спасибо, что не поленились мне ответить.

Comment: @AlexandrKarpulix так вы бы отметили ответ как  правильный

Comment: @cheops Но вот я проверил это еще раз и обнаружил, что в вашем примере не всё так гладко, т.к. он требует объявления пустого конструктора в дочернем классе, это я мог бы сделать и без его приватности в родительском, просто переопределив метод. Если конструктор не объявить, то php упадет с ошибкой "PHP Fatal error:  Call to private A::__construct() from invalid context" Поэтому тут есть еще над чем подумать. К тому же мне отредактировали вопрос. Я считаю, что сделали это с толком и расстановкой. Вопрос пока считаю открытым.

Comment: вы спросили про конструктор, про это и отредактировали.  В данном примере конструктор наследника (в php) замещает private конструктор родительского класса. Вы вполне можете набить его функционалом (в том числе, дублирующим действия родителя/дополняющего родителя), чтобы он выполнял нужные вам действия

Comment: я отмечу ваш вопрос ответом, если не найду другого объяснения. Спасибо вам за ваше внимание к проблеме. Я это очень ценю.

Comment: ответ давал cheops, а не я.

Answer (score 3):

Наследование в программировании подразумевает расширение функционала, а не наоборот. Таким образом, при наследовании мы можем добавить в классы-наследники новые свойства и методы, но не имеем возможности удалить что-то, определенное в классе-предке. Максимум что мы можем сделать, это определить метод или свойство как приватное, как уже написал **@cheops**, однако это не означает приватный элемент не будет унаследован, он просто будет не доступен для непосредственного обращения в классах-наследниках, но будет унаследован в любом случае.

Если же у вас возникает ситуация когда нужно запретить наследование отдельных элементов - это может означать одно из двух: либо не верно выбран класс-предок, либо ошибка при проектировании дерева наследования.

Для полноты картины стоит заметить, что в некоторых языках отдельные элементы могут не наследоваться, НО, такие элементы классов и их особенности при наследовании определяются спецификацией языка, они постоянны для всех классов в данном языке и данным поведением нельзя управлять из кода. В качестве примера могу привести отсутствие наследования статических элементов класса в C#.

**UPD:**
Конструктор, как и деструктор, является инфраструктурным методом и, несмотря на то, что определяется в коде класса, не является в полной мере методом этого класса, т.к. к нему нельзя обратиться ни через экземпляр, ни через сам класс. Единственный способ обратиться к конструктору - специальные инструкции языка для размещения нового объекта. В разных языках, поведение конструкторов при наследовании разное, например C# - последовательно вызывает конструкторы всех базовых классов, поэтому дочерний класс может не иметь собственный конструктор. Но фактически конструктор не наследуется.

Что касается сравнения наследования, как принципа ООП с наследованием в жизни, то это распространенное заблуждение, которое с разной степенью подробности обсуждается в любой более менее серьезной книге по ООП. Вообще в жизни можно обнаружить массу примеров наследования, которые невозможно воспроизвести средствами программного наследования, в разных случаях выходят из ситуации оп разному, например определением набора интерфейсов вместо дерева наследования.

**@strangeqargo**

> ...Вы можете добавить функций (в наследующем классе станет больше
>   функций), но это не означает, что наследник будет обладать большими
>   возможностями, чем предок. если вы унаследуете car:vehicle, car будет
>   "специфичней" чем vehicle и не может плавать/летать/телепортироваться,
>   хотя vehicle может.

Вы правы, но лишь отчасти. Да, в базовом классе мы определяем всего лишь общий для всего транспорта метод `перемещение`, и это будет то самое обобщение без конкретики о котором вы говорите, НО, когда дело дойдет до реального перемещения объекта - нам потребуется конкретика, как именно ехать, на каком принципе лететь, какими силами телепортироваться. И в данном случае, сказать что класс `vehicle` может больше чем `car` не совсем правильно, да, теоретически он может все, но пока не будут созданы соответствующие производные классы для реализации той или иной, или даже всех сразу функций перемещения, он фактически не может ничего. Более того, данный пример скорее следует отнести к принципу полиморфизма, т.к. ни кто не запретит мне определить полет, как один из возможных вариантов перемещения автомобиля.

**@Alexandr Karpulix**

> Например мягкая глина. Она имеет свойство которое помогает принимать
>   её любые формы. Все изделия из нее являются прямым её наследником,
>   имея одинаковый химический состав и, возможно, цвет. Но вот её
>   мягкость доступна только в её родительском классе, изделия же тверды.

Мягкость в данном случае свойство а не метод, в этом и разница. Кусок глины можно положить в печь и изменить это свойство, он станет твердым, оставаясь все тем же куском глины, равно как и необожженный горшок останется мягким как и исходный материал, оставаясь при этом конкретным глиняным изделием. Свойства могут определять применимость конкретного объекта в конкретном случае, не меняют суть объекта. Если горшок предназначен для хранения жидкости, то не важно мягкий он или твердый, свою задачу он выполнит. Опять же в данном случае не стоит рассматривать горшок как производное от глины. Глина, материал горшка. Ни кто не мешает выдолбить такой же горшок из дерева. При этом он перестанет быть глиняным, но останется горшком, а значит материал - свойство.

PS: Прошу прощения за лекцию %)

Comment: добавлю также, что это ко всему прочему будет нарушением принципа подстановки Барбары Лисков - явный признак того, что иерархия классов построена неправильно.

Comment: Конструктор сам по себе очень специфичный случай. Кроме того, наследование в программировании (и в жизни) подразумевает изменение (как расширение, так и сужение) функционала. Вы можете добавить функций (в наследующем классе станет больше функций), но это не означает, что наследник будет обладать большими возможностями, чем предок. если вы унаследуете car:vehicle, car будет "специфичней" чем vehicle и не может плавать/летать/телепортироваться, хотя vehicle может.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за пояснение. Я кое-что уже испрввил в проекте. Я сам думал, где в жизни можно найти такое приватное свойство, и нашел. Например мягкая глина. Она имеет свойство которое помогает принимать её любые формы. Все изделия из нее являются прямым её наследником, имея одинаковый химический состав и, возможно, цвет. Но вот её мягкость доступна только в её родительском классе, изделия же тверды. Однако мягкость может и  была бы доступна им, но для этого нужен будет свой метод. Это я к тому, что не обязательно может присутствовать "ошибка при проектировании дерева наследования".

Comment: Добавил про конструкторы, и ответил на приведенные примеры.

Comment: с++ не требует явного объявления конструкторов в любом классе, а в php конструктор (как минимум родительского класса) можно вызвать напрямую. Более того, вы вполне можете унаследовать некоторый конкретный класс и специально ограничить реализацию его методов (условно говоря чтобы раненая птица при попытке вызова fly() только квакала). В принципе, вы правы, что обсуждаете ОО-дизайн, только это все же не ответ.

Comment: На сайте php.net указано:

_Замечание: Конструкторы в классах-родителях не вызываются 
автоматически, если класс-потомок определяет собственный 
конструктор. Чтобы вызвать конструктор, объявленный в ?родительском классе, следует обратиться к методу parent::__construct() внутри конструктора класса-потомка. Если в классе-потомке не определен конструктор, то он может наследоваться от родительского класса как обычный метод (если он не определен как приватный)._
Думаю тут во всём виной то, что если не объявить конструктор, то будет осуществлена попытка вызова конструктора родителя.

Comment: @strangeqargo считать ли вопрос ответом, все таки решает автор вопроса. Я не претендую на единственно верный ответ и, если вы заметили, я сослался на уже опубликованный ответ, дополнив его необходимой на мой взгляд теорией. В C++ конструктор обязан быть у каждого класса, просто если вы его не описали, компилятор сделает это за вас, разница не принципиальна, но правку все же внесу. И опять же, пример с птицей - относится к применению полиморфизма.

Comment: @rdorn В С++ не обязан, я могу создать класс, у которого нет конструкторов, но я не смогу создать объекты этого класса. хотя, скорее всего, смогу вызывать статические методы

Comment: @strangeqargo https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s16xw1a8.aspx можете это опровергнуть ссылкой на документацию? я понимаю что MS не единственный производитель компиляторов и может понимать стандарты по своему, поэтому и спрашиваю

Comment: @rdorn в конце первого абзаца по вашей ссылке: `Это поведение можно переопределить, объявив конструктор по умолчанию как удаленный.` MS сейчас достаточно хорошую команду по C++ собрал, они норм догоняют стандарт и даже предлагают хорошие новые решения.

Comment: @strangeqargo ок, убедили, конструкторы это вообще отдельная тема, и почти у всех они работают по своему, со своими тараканами.